# CSS word-spacing specification

Tags: css

Are there any characters that CSS word-spacing does not break on?

For example suppose I give my element a large `word-spacing` size (equal to element width), such that it breaks on each word. So for this:

```
<div class="break">THIS BREAKS ON EACH LINE</div>
```

I'll get:

```
---------
| THIS
| BREAKS
| ON
| EACH
| LINE
|--------
```

Is there any character I can use that will not break lines. For example:

```
<div class="break">THIS BREAKS & EACH LINE</div>
```

I want no break after the ampersand:

```
---------
| THIS
| BREAKS
| & EACH          <<<--- Here
| LINE
|--------
```

Comment: did you see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gG78X/1/)?

Comment: it's  a part of work like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `white-space` affects spacing between “words” in a technical sense: a word is a maximal sequence of non-whitespace characters. So, in effect, it affects all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). However, [fixed-width space characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) such as `&ensp;` are not counted as whitespace, so you can write

```
THIS BREAKS &&ensp;EACH LINE
```

if you do not want the spacing between “&” and “EACH” to expand. This is not completely safe, though, since browsers may some day treat characters differently. They already changed the way `&nbsp;` is handled; it used to be “non-stretchable” but isn’t any more.

So the safe way is really

```
THIS BREAKS <span class=nows>& EACH</span> LINE
```

with CSS

```
.nows { word-spacing: 0 }
```

Preventing line breaks is a different question, often asked and answered at SO. Using the safe way above, you could just use a no-break space instead of a normal space:

```
THIS BREAKS <span class=nows>&&nbsp;EACH</span> LINE
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a decent workaround using the "thin non breaking space" character (`&#8239;`) which behaves properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6KW/4/

Comment: A nice trick, though it fails on old versions of IE, which may look in vain for a glyph of the character and render a small box instead.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I only care for modern browsers for this project, but good point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) to prevent a break...however this will [maintain your word spacing](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6KW/).

Your best bet would be to throw a bit of [jQuery in there](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6KW/3/), a la:

CSS

```
.break{
    word-spacing:50px;
    width:50px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="break">THIS BREAKS ON & EACH LINE</div>
```

jQuery

```
var txt = $('.break');
var ls=txt.css('word-spacing');
txt.html(txt.text().replace(' & ', '<span style="margin:0 -'+ls+' 0 0;"> &&nbsp;</span>'));
```

Comment: Yeah this was my first hunch, but the spacing is unacceptable. I would expect it simply not to break :)

Comment: @Yuval Adam - you'll need to use JS if you are setting CSS spacing.. please see updated answer

Comment: This is the workaround we're looking into, simply by inserting a `<span style="word-spacing:0">&nbsp;</span>`, but I'd really rather use an actual character that is a whitespace and considered part of a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` like this:

```
<div class="break">THIS BREAKS &&nbsp;EACH LINE</div>
```

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gG78X/)

Comment: See @ExtPro's answer, this creates unwanted space.

Comment: Your demo does not include word-spacing at all.

Comment: i have placed the demo at top that is under your question.

Comment: Again, your demo is a simple div with a narrow width and no word-spacing. I'm talking about a wide div with a wide word spacing.

Comment: what ever you are talking about this works perfectly as if you define like this &&nbsp;yourtext